# Insert row in proper order on table based off of primary key.

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I like being able to go to phpmyadmin and seeing my rows ordered.
Is there an easy way to insert a row into the correct order by it's primary key?

Comment: click on the column name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no order you can rely on.

> Unless you specify ORDER BY, there are no guarantees about what rows
>   will be returned first.
>
> But in practice, the order will typically match the clustered index
>   order, and will not vary between calls. Don't rely on this behaviour.

[Does MySQL's LIMIT keyword guarantee order of returned data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023675/does-mysqls-limit-keyword-guarantee-order-of-returned-data)

> There is no default sort order. Even if the table has a clustered
>   index, you are not guaranteed to get the results in that order. You
>   must use an order by clause if you want a specific order.

[SQL best practice to deal with default sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order)

> Just insert the data; tables are not fundamentally ordered. The only ordering of table results occurs when you define it yourself in your select statement.

[Is it possible to insert data into the mid section of a table using the INSERT command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127169/is-it-possible-to-insert-data-into-the-mid-section-of-a-table-using-the-insert-co)

> You can't. There is no such thing.
>
> To be precise: in MyISAM engine, current order is whatever the order
>   was when the last ALTER TABLE ORDER BY was performed, modified by all
>   the deletions and insertions since.
>
> InnoDB just sorts the tables as it wishes.

[view current table order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842996/view-current-table-order)

> However be aware of the advice from another poster above: the order in
>   which rows are returned without an ORDER BY clause is arbitrary and
>   may change without notification. It would be best to amend your table
>   if at all possible.

[Reverse the “natural order” of a MySQL table without ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779180/reverse-the-natural-order-of-a-mysql-table-without-order-by)

.... and maaany more.